# Azure AD MFA user rollout

Tags: azure

I have had a user account compromised during the roll out of MFA to all users.

Azure MFA in cloud setup and O365 for all users.

MFA was rolled out in batches and the account compromised was in between one of the batches. i have no history of what users were in each batch, i took over from someone else that is now gone.

What i am trying to find out, is when the MFA was enabled for this user.

I have gone through the Azure Audit Logs/Reports and also used PowerShell to try and view the data however everything i can find is only the status of 'Enable' and nothing to do with WHEN it was enabled.

I have googled it and have come up empty-handed other than finding the status or the last sync time.

I'm assuming it is not possible but would like confirmation on that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How does knowing when MFA was enabled help? What are you trying to accomplish by finding out the when?

Comment: They are worried that the compromised account was able to access the user's documents within the time they had access. If MFA was enabled before the account was compromised then they wouldn't have been able to authenticate and access the user's documents.

Comment: Well that doesn't quite make sense. If the account was compromised then it was compromised, regardless of MFA. Or am I missing something in your logic?

Comment: Ok, so if MFA was not enabled when the user was compromised, the 'hacker' can log onto outlook using users email and password and view everything in there, forward etc.
If MFA was enabled, the 'hacker' would try to log into outlook using users email and password, then be prompted for MFA (enter the code we sent by text), which the 'hacker' would not be able to enter.

Comment: So, i need to know if MFA was enabled before the compromise or after the compromise. That way i can say "no need to worry, the MFA would have prevented access to the users documents" or i can do further investigations into what documents may have been viewed.

Comment: If the account was compromised then it follows that the perpetrator was able to log in as the user. If MFA was enabled and the perpetrator was not able to log in as the user then the account was not compromised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that you will be able to figure out the date of MFA enablement for concrete user, but you can look on Sign in logs with filtering by user and application https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-sign-ins#sign-ins-report

MFA Required column will indicate if MFA was used to sign in or not and MFA Result will indicate if validation was successfully passed or failed.